# Docker for Windows Dockerfile

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, docker-for-windows, docker

I am trying to create a Docker image for a Windows container with a VSTS build agent.  I have the following Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-sac2016

# Set up environment
ENV AGENT_VERSION 2.129.1
ENV AGENT_TYPE build

# Download/extract the VSTS agent software
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 
https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/${env:AGENT_VERSION}/vsts-agent-win-x64-${env:AGENT_VERSION}.zip -outfile agent.zip; `
    Expand-Archive agent.zip; `
    Remove-Item -Force agent.zip;
WORKDIR C:\agent

# Configure the agent and run it as a Windows service
# Users can pass "--deploymentGroup" to the "docker run" command if they want to run the agent as a deployment group (release) agent.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
ENTRYPOINT C:\agent\config.cmd --unattended --auth pat --runAsService --addDeploymentGroupTags
```

And I'm getting this very confusing error from the `ENTRYPOINT` line:

```
-Sta : The term '-Sta' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Comman ...
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Sta:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
An error occurred: PowerShell is not installed. Minimum required version: 3.0
```

I've taken a look at the [`config.cmd`](https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.129.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.129.1.zip) script that gets downloaded, and it has the following nasty statement on line 26:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$VerbosePreference = %VERBOSE_ARG% ; Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '%~dp0' | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f $_.FullName) ; $_ } | Unblock-File | Out-Null ; Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath '%~dp0bin', '%~dp0externals' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\.(ps1|psd1|psm1)$' } | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f $_.FullName) ; $_ } | Unblock-File | Out-Null ; Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '%~dp0externals\vstsom', '%~dp0externals\vstshost' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\.(dll|exe)$' } | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f $_.FullName) ; $_ } | Unblock-File | Out-Null"
```

So that line appears to be the line that is failing in my container, but I have no idea why.  The aspnetcore-build image ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/blob/master/2.0/nanoserver-sac2016/sdk/Dockerfile)) that I'm deriving from is itself derived from a microsoft/dotnet image ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/2.0/sdk/nanoserver-sac2016/amd64/Dockerfile)), which sets the `SHELL` to `powershell`, so I know for a fact that PowerShell is installed in the container.  Is there some kind of syntax error occurring as a result of calling this .cmd script from Docker?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware that Microsoft already publishes a Dockerfile for Windows build agents? https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker

Comment: Yes I am aware, but according to Microsoft: `Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 are the currently supported OSes, but there are plans for Windows support`.  I need Windows for a particular build task to succeed, but apparently Microsoft doesn't even support its own OS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Windows image file: [vsts-agent-docker/windows/servercore/10.0.14393](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/tree/master/windows/servercore/10.0.14393)

It run agent as this:

```
& .\bin\Agent.Listener.exe configure --unattended `
    --agent "$env:VSTS_AGENT" `
    --url "https://$env:VSTS_ACCOUNT.visualstudio.com" `
    --auth PAT `
    --token "$env:VSTS_TOKEN" `
    --pool "$env:VSTS_POOL" `
    --work "$env:VSTS_WORK" `
    --replace

& .\bin\Agent.Listener.exe run
```

About how to use this image: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use-these-images

Comment: I did see the Dockerfile for this Windows image in the Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker repo, but I just figured it was still in development since it hasn't been deployed to the Docker Store.  Why has it not been?

Comment: No sure why it isn't deployed to Docker Store, but what's the result after trying with it?

Comment: after cloning and building the Dockerfile, that image works great!  Took me a minute to set up the environment correctly since there's no documentation, but the agent configured correctly and appeared in VSTS.  If you provide some instructions on how to set up and `run` that Dockerfile in your answer, then I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image doesn't include any other software, not even .NET Core.  There is another Dockerfile in a standard/2017 subfolder that *does* include the "standard" software, including Git and NPM.  However, it requires the Windows image as a base image.  More importantly, I don't see any way yet to run it as a deployment agent rather than a normal build agent.  So I think everything will work, there are just a lot of hoops to jump through...

Comment: You can update the dockerfile per to the requirement. You said that "If you provide some instructions on how to set up and run that Dockerfile in your answer", since the agent configured correctly and appeared in VSTS, what's the problem of running that Dockerfile? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: I meant that the answer would be more complete if it included some basic instructions on how to use the image, as it took me a while to figure out that the Linux set up instructions applied to the Windows one as well. I just edited your answer.

Comment: Also, your answer did not address the strange `PowerShell is not installed` error that I was getting.  Do you have any idea why that was happening, or how to fix it?  I've been getting that same error in almost every Windows Dockerfile that I try to make...

Comment: @Rabadash8820 The issue may related to the nano server, the -sta argument can't be recognized, check this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/483